# Django model allow only once in many

Tags: django, django-models, relationship

Please excuse the title but I'm not sure howto put this into words.
I have a model "card" and a model "computer":

```
class card(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(
    verbose_name = 'Name',
    max_length=50,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)
serial=models.CharField(
    verbose_name = 'Serial',
    max_length=50,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)

class computer(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(
    verbose_name = 'Name',
    max_length=50,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)
slot1 = models.OneToOneField(
    'card',
    related_name='cardslot1',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    verbose_name = 'Slot 1',
)
slot2 = models.OneToOneField(
    'card', 
    related_name='cardslot2',
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    verbose_name = 'Slot 2',
)
```

(Of course that this computer model is invalid)
The cards are unique and should only be allowed to be used in one slot - of any computer. What's the best way to achieve this? I was thinking about a in-between table, something like

**card** n-1 **cardcomputer** n-1 **computer**

but I'm hoping there's a better way I'm not seeing right now.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yagus answer is correct, but here's a pure model alternative.

```py
class Card(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Name',
        max_length=50,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    serial = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Serial',
        max_length=50,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )


class Slot(models.Model):
    card = models.OneToOneField(Card,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    computer = models.ForeignKey('Computer',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='slots'
    )


class Computer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='Name',
        max_length=50,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

This way you have flexibility to add/change slots per computer in the admin panel and things are imho more readable than the constraints.

You can still access `Computer.slots` thanks to the related name.

Comment: Now I would only need to figure out howto make the slots and the cards selectable from a form for new computers (outside the admin panel). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [constraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/) meta option for your model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import CheckConstraint, Q

class computer(models.Model)

    name=models.CharField(
        verbose_name = 'Name',
        max_length=50,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    slot1 = models.OneToOneField(
        'card',
        related_name='cardslot1',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name = 'Slot 1',
    )
    slot2 = models.OneToOneField(
        'card', 
        related_name='cardslot2',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name = 'Slot 2',
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check = ~Q(slot1=slot2), 
                name = 'unique_slot',
            ),
        ]
```

Comment: I seem to be doing this wrong, while makemigrations I always get
NameError: name 'slot2' is not defined

Comment: @tesago, Well, you need to define your fields of course. I've only stated the Meta class for simplicity.

Comment: I have slot1 and slot2 defined as I did before, still I'm getting the name error. I even copied your updated code, I don't see what I'm donig wrong.

Comment: @tesago I've put the Meta class after the definition of fields. This should do the job.